# Stayed alive and end well

Tags: word-choice

If I am talking about a fire in a building, can I say "Everything ended well. All stayed alive and well." Do my sentences sound natural?

Comment: You can say this... it is not grammatically incorrect. As to sounding natural, it could sound a bit stilted. It depends on context.

Comment: How would you rephrase it?

Comment: A building fire can hardly be said to have 'ended well' even if all the occupants survived!

Comment: As I said, it depends on the speaker's context. Is someone speaking to a friend telling them this, is it part of an essay for a teacher describing their experiences?

Comment: @KateBunting depends how fast they put it out ;) if the damage is minimal, a relieved owner might very well say things "ended well", because once the building was on fire, the end result was the best it could have been under the circumstances!

Comment: I would rephrase it as: _Everything ended well. No casualties whatsoever._ __or__ _Everything ended well, and there were no casualties._

Comment: Yes, it is part of an essay.

Comment: It would be unusual to describe a fire as **ending well**. People would be more likely to say something like: **Fortunately the fire was quickly extinguished. There was little damage and no harm was done.**